# How to disable the word "new*" for each newly created method and class in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide

### **IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.3 (Ultimate Edition)**

For every newly created method/class a word **new*** is added on the top of the method/class as shown in the image below. **How can I disable it?**

[image]

Comment: Look up "inlay hints" in the settings. I don't know what this particular hint is called, but there should be a checkbox in the inlay hints section to turn this off.

Comment: Hi @Sweeper thanks for helping me out. When I right-clicked on the new* word I found the option to hide the "inlay hint". Thank again.

Answer (score 2):

As @Sweeper mentioned above, this is an "**inlay hint**".

To **disable/hide** it, **right-click** the "inlay hint" and hide/configure it as in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may disable or enable this code author inlay hint (just like others) in `Settings > Editor > Inlay Hints`:

[image: Settings -> Editor -> Inlay Hints]